# Vertical align link text in a percentage height list

Tags: css, height, vertical-alignment

I want to align the link text vertically in the `<li>` list. I tried several ways, but couldn't find the solution. I must keep the percentage height.

A sample version of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/kr0mf4oe/3/

```css
div#html {
  height: 500px;
}
div#main {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
ul#list {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
ul#list>li {
  height: 20%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px white solid;
}
li>a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="html">
  <div id="main">
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="leaf1">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf2">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf3">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf4">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf5">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS table + table-cell. As table-cell has the `vertical-align` feature.

```
ul#list>li {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
ul#list>li>a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
div#html {
  height: 500px;
}
div#main {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
ul#list {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  list-style: none; /*added*/
  padding-left: 0; /*added*/
}
ul#list>li {
  height: 20%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px white solid;
  display: table; /*added*/
  width: 100%; /*added*/
}
ul#list>li>a {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell; /*added*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*added*/
}
```

```html
<div id="html">
  <div id="main">
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="leaf1">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf2">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf3">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf4">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf5">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use the CSS3 [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), with `justify-content:center` for center horizontally, and `align-items:center` for center vertically.

```
ul#list>li>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
div#html {
  height: 500px;
}
div#main {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
ul#list {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  list-style: none; /*added*/
  padding-left: 0; /*added*/
}
ul#list>li {
  height: 20%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px white solid;
}
ul#list>li>a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; /*added*/
  justify-content: center; /*added*/
  align-items: center; /*added*/
}
```

```html
<div id="html">
  <div id="main">
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="leaf1">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf2">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf3">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf4">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf5">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use tables, you can also do it like this:

```css
div#html{
  height:500px;
}

div#main{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

ul#list{
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
}

ul#list>li{
  height:20%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px white solid;
  position: relative; /* new */
}

li>a{
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
li>a>span{ /* new */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="html">
  <div id="main">
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="leaf1">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><span>text1<br />text1.1</span></a> <!-- wrap your text in a span -->
      </li>
      <li class="leaf2">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><span>text2</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf3">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><span>text3</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf4">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><span>text4</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf5">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><span>text5</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting the text to be vertically aligned within the green box that is the list element?  If so:

Tell the `<li>` to display as a table and then you can tell the `<a>` within it to vertical-align, so split up your CSS for the li>a into 2 tags as so:

```
li{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```